# STM32F103 ADC via DMA - sequence scan to RAM can't make it work as expected

Tags: adc, stm32, dma

I'm using an STM32F103C8T6 BluePill board and CubeMX generated init code (Low-level libs) to setup the ADC + DMA to sequentially scan though 8 channels and write to an array in RAM. However, it either doesn't work at all, or (when configured as in the code below) seems to just convert/capture channel 1 (PA0) 8 times.

I've trawled the data-sheet, appnotes, CubeMX example code, numerous examples online and for the life of me I can't see what's wrong in my setup - so I'm hoping someone here might spot it!

All the other stuff (clocks, GPIO pins etc.) is the standard boilerplate LL init code generated by CubeMX so hopefully no surprises.

Code calls `MX_ADC1_Init()` and then `ADC_DMA_Start()` to kick things off, but the contents of RawVals is always 8 of the same reading plus or minus a bit or two of noise (but the values all follow the voltage on PA0).

```c
#define NUM_ADCS    8
uint16_t RawVals[NUM_ADCS];


/* ADC1 init function */
void MX_ADC1_Init(void)
{
    LL_ADC_InitTypeDef ADC_InitStruct = {0};
    LL_ADC_CommonInitTypeDef ADC_CommonInitStruct = {0};
    LL_ADC_REG_InitTypeDef ADC_REG_InitStruct = {0};

    LL_GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
    /* Peripheral clock enable */
    LL_APB2_GRP1_EnableClock(LL_APB2_GRP1_PERIPH_ADC1);

    LL_APB2_GRP1_EnableClock(LL_APB2_GRP1_PERIPH_GPIOA);
    /**ADC1 GPIO Configuration  
     *  PA0-WKUP   ------> ADC1_IN0
     *  PA1   ------> ADC1_IN1
     *  PA4   ------> ADC1_IN4
     *  PA5   ------> ADC1_IN5
     *  PA6   ------> ADC1_IN6
     *  PA7   ------> ADC1_IN7 
     */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = LL_GPIO_PIN_0|LL_GPIO_PIN_1|LL_GPIO_PIN_4|LL_GPIO_PIN_5|LL_GPIO_PIN_6|LL_GPIO_PIN_7;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = LL_GPIO_MODE_ANALOG;
    LL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    /* ADC1 DMA Init */

    /* ADC1 Init */
    LL_DMA_SetDataTransferDirection(ADC_DMA, ADC_DMA_CH, LL_DMA_DIRECTION_PERIPH_TO_MEMORY);

    //LL_DMA_SetChannelPriorityLevel(ADC_DMA, ADC_DMA_CH, LL_DMA_PRIORITY_LOW);
    LL_DMA_SetChannelPriorityLevel(ADC_DMA, ADC_DMA_CH, LL_DMA_PRIORITY_MEDIUM);

    LL_DMA_SetMode(ADC_DMA, ADC_DMA_CH, LL_DMA_MODE_CIRCULAR);

    LL_DMA_SetPeriphIncMode(ADC_DMA, ADC_DMA_CH, LL_DMA_PERIPH_NOINCREMENT);

    LL_DMA_SetMemoryIncMode(ADC_DMA, ADC_DMA_CH, LL_DMA_MEMORY_INCREMENT);

    LL_DMA_SetPeriphSize(ADC_DMA, ADC_DMA_CH, LL_DMA_PDATAALIGN_HALFWORD);

    LL_DMA_SetMemorySize(ADC_DMA, ADC_DMA_CH, LL_DMA_MDATAALIGN_HALFWORD);

    // LL_DMA_ConfigAddresses(DMA_TypeDef *DMAx, uint32_t Channel, uint32_t SrcAddress, uint32_t DstAddress, uint32_t Direction)
    LL_DMA_ConfigAddresses(ADC_DMA, ADC_DMA_CH, LL_ADC_DMA_GetRegAddr(ADC1, LL_ADC_DMA_REG_REGULAR_DATA), (uint32_t)RawVals, LL_DMA_DIRECTION_PERIPH_TO_MEMORY);

    LL_DMA_SetDataLength(ADC_DMA, ADC_DMA_CH, DMA_DATA_SIZE*2); // Size in bytes

    /**
     * Common config
     */
    ADC_InitStruct.DataAlignment = LL_ADC_DATA_ALIGN_RIGHT; // 12-bits right-aligned
    ADC_InitStruct.SequencersScanMode = LL_ADC_SEQ_SCAN_ENABLE; // Sequentially scan through channels
    LL_ADC_Init(ADC1, &ADC_InitStruct);
    ADC_CommonInitStruct.Multimode = LL_ADC_MULTI_INDEPENDENT; // ADC1 operating alone
    LL_ADC_CommonInit(__LL_ADC_COMMON_INSTANCE(ADC1), &ADC_CommonInitStruct);
    ADC_REG_InitStruct.TriggerSource = LL_ADC_REG_TRIG_SOFTWARE;
    ADC_REG_InitStruct.SequencerLength = 8;
    ADC_REG_InitStruct.SequencerDiscont = LL_ADC_REG_SEQ_DISCONT_DISABLE;
    //ADC_REG_InitStruct.ContinuousMode = LL_ADC_REG_CONV_SINGLE; // Run through conversions once & then stop
    ADC_REG_InitStruct.ContinuousMode =  LL_ADC_REG_CONV_CONTINUOUS;
    ADC_REG_InitStruct.DMATransfer = LL_ADC_REG_DMA_TRANSFER_UNLIMITED;
    LL_ADC_REG_Init(ADC1, &ADC_REG_InitStruct);

    /**
     * Configure Regular Channel
     */
    LL_ADC_REG_SetSequencerRanks(ADC1, LL_ADC_REG_RANK_1, LL_ADC_CHANNEL_0);
    LL_ADC_SetChannelSamplingTime(ADC1, LL_ADC_CHANNEL_0, REGULAR_CHANNEL_SAMPLE_TIME);

    /**
     * Configure Regular Channel
     */
    LL_ADC_REG_SetSequencerRanks(ADC1, LL_ADC_REG_RANK_2, LL_ADC_CHANNEL_1);
    LL_ADC_SetChannelSamplingTime(ADC1, LL_ADC_CHANNEL_1, REGULAR_CHANNEL_SAMPLE_TIME);

    /**
     * Configure Regular Channel
     */
    LL_ADC_REG_SetSequencerRanks(ADC1, LL_ADC_REG_RANK_3, LL_ADC_CHANNEL_4);
    LL_ADC_SetChannelSamplingTime(ADC1, LL_ADC_CHANNEL_4, REGULAR_CHANNEL_SAMPLE_TIME);

    /**
     * Configure Regular Channel
     */
    LL_ADC_REG_SetSequencerRanks(ADC1, LL_ADC_REG_RANK_4, LL_ADC_CHANNEL_5);
    LL_ADC_SetChannelSamplingTime(ADC1, LL_ADC_CHANNEL_5, REGULAR_CHANNEL_SAMPLE_TIME);

    /**
     * Configure Regular Channel
     */
    LL_ADC_REG_SetSequencerRanks(ADC1, LL_ADC_REG_RANK_5, LL_ADC_CHANNEL_6);
    LL_ADC_SetChannelSamplingTime(ADC1, LL_ADC_CHANNEL_6, REGULAR_CHANNEL_SAMPLE_TIME);

    /**
     * Configure Regular Channel
     */
    LL_ADC_REG_SetSequencerRanks(ADC1, LL_ADC_REG_RANK_6, LL_ADC_CHANNEL_7);
    LL_ADC_SetChannelSamplingTime(ADC1, LL_ADC_CHANNEL_7, REGULAR_CHANNEL_SAMPLE_TIME);

    /**
     * Configure Regular Channel
     */
    LL_ADC_REG_SetSequencerRanks(ADC1, LL_ADC_REG_RANK_7, LL_ADC_CHANNEL_TEMPSENSOR);
    LL_ADC_SetChannelSamplingTime(ADC1, LL_ADC_CHANNEL_TEMPSENSOR, LL_ADC_SAMPLINGTIME_239CYCLES_5);
    LL_ADC_SetCommonPathInternalCh(__LL_ADC_COMMON_INSTANCE(ADC1), LL_ADC_PATH_INTERNAL_TEMPSENSOR);

    /**
     * Configure Regular Channel
     */
    LL_ADC_REG_SetSequencerRanks(ADC1, LL_ADC_REG_RANK_8, LL_ADC_CHANNEL_VREFINT);
    LL_ADC_SetChannelSamplingTime(ADC1, LL_ADC_CHANNEL_VREFINT, LL_ADC_SAMPLINGTIME_239CYCLES_5);
    LL_ADC_SetCommonPathInternalCh(__LL_ADC_COMMON_INSTANCE(ADC1), LL_ADC_PATH_INTERNAL_VREFINT);

}


void ADC_DMA_Start(void)
{
    LL_ADC_Enable(ADC1);
    LL_DMA_EnableChannel(ADC_DMA, ADC_DMA_CH);
    LL_ADC_REG_StartConversionSWStart(ADC1);
}
```

Comment: your settings look correct. have you tried using the HAL driver instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found the problem and it's in the initialisation code generated by STM32CubeMX itself!

This line in MX_ADC_Init():

```
ADC_REG_InitStruct.SequencerLength = 8;
```

should be:

```
ADC_REG_InitStruct.SequencerLength = LL_ADC_REG_SEQ_SCAN_ENABLE_8RANKS;
```

which expands to:

```
#define LL_ADC_REG_SEQ_SCAN_ENABLE_8RANKS  (ADC_SQR1_L_2 | ADC_SQR1_L_1 | ADC_SQR1_L_0)
```

in the headers, which in raw terms is:

```
((0x4U << (20U)) | (0x2U << (20U)) | (0x1U << (20U)))
```

So basically CubeMX was missing out the bit-shift or is expecting `LL_ADC_REG_Init` to insert it.